# Why does truncate fail for sizes above 2043G in ext3?

Tags: kernel, filesystems

Why does this work:

```
truncate -s 2043G foo
```

...while this fails:

```
truncate -s 2044G foo
```

Why 2043 gigabytes, of all values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using a filesystem that has a 2TB maximum file size (for example, ext3 with a 4KB or 8KB block size). `truncate` won't let you specify a target file size greater than the maximum your file system supports; 2044GB is very close to 2TB. I'm not sure why it's not exactly 2048GB that causes the problem; it's probably something internal to ext3's method of storing files

Answer (score 3):

That's a limitation of the file system you use. Here ZFS creates a whopping 7 Exabyte sparse file:

```
$ truncate -s 7E foo
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r--   1 jlliagre 8070450532247928832 Nov  9 16:49 foo
```

Comment: I figured as much, sorry for not having specified this.